# JMeter encoding issue on "application/soap+msbin1"

Tags: jmeter

Working on JMeter and trying to send the soap request to server and shows the below error msg.

> Error Msg:- Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+msbin1' was not the expected type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

We need help to encode XML to 'application/soap+msbin1' format.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but I encountered a similar issue - I had a template for SOAP request which uses embedded-binary XML (xop:Include cid="...") and had to scratch my head to figure out how to do that with the stock HTTP Request.

The answer: you can't - not in a simple way. To solve the issue, I ended up customizing JMeter (I also looked at HTTPRawRequest as well but it doesn't seem to support https and I would have to rewrite a lot of the test script to use that). Since HTTP request does 99% of the job, the quickest way to support binary data is to change the source code to handle binary data.

The main issues are two: the Function interface in JMeter is designed around returning String, not byte[]. So already __FileToString() (which I used to read an external binary file to use) encodes the content of the file . Secondly, the HTTP Request Sampler and HTTPHC4Impl itself (excluding the "upload file" bit) encodes the parts of the HTTP request before sending it over to the wire.

Changing that implied changes in Function, AbstractFunction,  CompoundVariable and create a new function class FileToStringBinary which encode the binary data in a way that it can be decoded after (by changes made to HTTPHC4Impl).

If I have the time I'll find someplace where to post the idea and the source (can't submit to JMeter because my update to  HTTPHC4Impl is limited to handle the specific requests I need to test, where the embedded binary is in a multipart/related part, and I have no time or inclination to handle the general cases), but if you still need help to make it work, drop a line.